# Wrapper class for thread-safe objects

Tags: delphi, concurrency, indy

I have recently played around with one demo [opensource](https://sourceforge.net/projects/indy10clieservr/?source=directory)  project for the basic functionality of the INDY10 TCP/IP server and stumbled upon the problem of internal multitasking implementation  of INDY and its interaction with VCL components. Since there are many different topics in SO on the subject, I decided to make a simple client-server application and test some of the solutions and approaches suggested, at least the ones that I understood correctly. Below I would like to summarize and review an approach that was previously suggested on SO, and if possible listen to your expert opinion on the subject.

> Problem: Encapsulation the VCL for thread-safe usage inside an indy10-based client/server application.

Description of the Development Env.: 
Delphi Version: Delphi® XE2 Version 16.0
INDY Version 10.5.8.0
O.S. Windows 7 (32Bit)

As mentioned in the article ([ Is the VCL Thread-safe?]) (sorry I do not have enough reputation to post the link) special care should be taken when one wishes to use any kind of VCL components inside a multithreaded (multitasking) application. VCL is not thread safe, but can be used in a thread safe way!
The how and the why usually depend on the application at hand but one can attempt to generalize a bit and suggest some kind of general approach to this problem. First of all, as in the case of INDY10, one does not need to be explicitly parallelizing his code, i.e. create and execute multiple threads, in order to expose VCL to deadlocks and data inter dependencies.

In every sclient-server application, the server has to be able to handle multiple requests simultaneously, so naturally, INDY10 internally implements this functionality. This would mean that the INDY10 set of classes are responsible to manage the program's thread creation, execution and destruction procedures internally.

The most obvious place where our code is exposed to the inner workings of INDY10 and hence possible thread conflicts, is the IdTCPServerExecute (TIdTCPServer onExecute event) method.

Naturally, INDY10 provides classes (wrappers) that ensure thread-safe program flow, but since I did not manage to get enough explanation on their application and usage, I prefer a custom made approach.

Below I summarize a method ( the suggested technique is based on a previous comment I found in SO [How to use TIdThreadSafe class from Indy10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13111880/how-to-use-tidthreadsafe-class-from-indy10) ) that attempts (and presumably succeeds) in dealing with this problem:

> The question I tackle below is: How to make a specific class "MyClass" ThreadSafe?

The main idea is to create kind of a wrapper class that encapsulates "MyClass" and queues the threads that try to access it in First-In-First-Out principle. The underlying objects that are used for synchronization are [Windows's Critical Section Objects.].

In the context of a client-server application, "MyClass" will contain all thread unsafe functionality of our server, so we will try to ensure that those procedures and functions are not executed by more than one working thread simultaneously. This naturally means loss of parallelism of our code, but since the approach is simple and seems to be , in some cases this maybe a useful approach.

Wrapper class Implementation:

```
constructor TThreadSafeObject<T>.Create(originalObject: T);
begin
  tsObject := originalObject; // pass it already instantiated instance of MyClass
  tsCriticalSection:= TCriticalSection.Create; // Critical section Object
end;

destructor TThreadSafeObject<T>.Destroy();
begin
  FreeAndNil(tsObject);
  FreeAndNil(tsCriticalSection);
  inherited Destroy;

end;


function TThreadSafeObject<T>.Lock(): T;
begin
  tsCriticalSection.Enter;
  result:=tsObject;

end;

procedure TThreadSafeObject<T>.Unlock();
begin
  tsCriticalSection.Leave;
end;

procedure TThreadSafeObject<T>.FreeOwnership();
begin
  FreeAndNil(tsObject);
  FreeAndNil(tsCriticalSection);
end;
```

MyClass Definition:

```
MyClass = class

  public
    procedure drawRandomBitmap(abitmap: TBitmap); //Draw Random Lines on TCanvas
    function decToBin(i: LongInt): String; //convert decimal number to Bin. 
    procedure addLineToMemo(aLine: String; MemoFld: TMemo); // output message to TMemo
    function randomColor(): TColor; 
  end;
```

Usage:

Since threads execute in order and wait for the thread which has the current ownership of the critical section to finish (tsCriticalSection.Enter; and tsCriticalSection.Leave;) it is logical that if you want to manage that ownership relay,  you need one unique instance **TThreadSafeObject** (you can consider using the singleton pattern). so include:

```
tsMyclass:= TThreadSafeObject<MyClass>.Create(MyClass.Create);
```

in Form.Create and

```
tsMyclass.Destroy;
```

in Form.Close; Here tsMyclass is a global variable of type MyClass.

Usage:

Regarding the usage of MyClass try the following:

```
with tsMyclass.Lock do
try
  addLineToMemo('MemoLine1', Memo1);
  addLineToMemo('MemoLine2', Memo1);
  addLineToMemo('MemoLine3', Memo1);
finally
  // release ownership
  tsMyclass.unlock;
end;
```

, where Memo1 is an instance of a TMemo component on the form.

With this, we are supposed to ensure that anything that happens when tsMyClass is locked 
will be executed by only one thread at a time. An obvious drawback of this approach, however, is that since I have only one instance of tsMyclass, even if one thread is trying to draw for e.g. on the Canvas, while another is writing on the Memo, the first thread will have to wait for the second to finish and only then it will be able to carry out its job.

My questions here are:

1. Is the above suggested method correct? Am I still free of race
   conditions or do I have some "loopholes" in the code, from where
   data conflicts could occur?
2. How can one, in general, test for thread
   unsafety of his/her applicaiton?

I would like to stress that the above approach is in no way my own doing. It is basically a summary of the solution found in [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13111880/how-to-use-tidthreadsafe-class-from-indy10). Nevertheless, I have decided to post again in an attempt to get some kind of closure on the topic or a kind of proof of validity for the suggested solution. Besides, repetition is mother of all knowledge, as they say.

Comment: This question's is so long, I don't even know where to start.

Answer (score 4):

> With this, we are supposed to ensure that anything that happens when
>   tsMyClass is locked will be executed by only one thread at a time. An
>   obvious drawback of this approach, however, is that since I have only
>   one instance of tsMyclass, even if one thread is trying to draw for
>   e.g. on the Canvas, while another is writing on the Memo, the first
>   thread will have to wait for the second to finish and only then it
>   will be able to carry out its job.

I see one big problem here: the VCL (forms, drawing, etc...) lives on the main thread. Even if you block concurrent thread access, the updates need to be done in the context of the main thread. This is the part where you need to use Synhronize(), the big difference with a lock (Criticalsection) is that synchronized code is ran in the context of the main thread. The end result is basically the same, your threaded code is serialized and you lose the advantage of using threads in the first place.

Comment: Yes, you definately **CANNOT** access VCL UI controls from outside of the context of the main thread. Period. Putting a thread-safe lock around a UI control will not work, because the main thread does not respect the lock when it access the controls. Also, the `TWinControl.Handle` property has thread-affinity, and bad things happen if that affinity changes at runtime.

Comment: If you need threaded code to access the UI, you **MUST** delegate to the main thread to handle the access safely. `TThread` has `Synchronize()` and `Queue()` methods for that purpose. Indy also has its own `TIdSync` and `TIdNotify` classes for that purpose as well.

Comment: OK guys, so how about if I redefine MyClass to inherit from TThread and call its methods using for instance 'Synchronize(addLineToMemo)' etc. As far as I understood, Synchronize takes as input only procedures that have no input parameters. So to call addLineToMemo with the correct input data, I should set the input data as private fields of  MyClass (using a public wrapper method) and then call Synchronize(addLineToMemo) from withing that wrapper? Is that the thread safe way?

Comment: @Kenny, think about isolation, ideally your thread does not now about other entities (like a TMemo on your main form). expose events on your thread that synchronize with the main thread. So forexample your would have an onprogress event on your thread (called with Synchronize()) and your main form consumes that event...

Comment: @whosrdaddy I am not sure I understand what you mean. ALL I need to do is ensure that two consecutive updates of my TCanvas, for example, do not interfere but are rather executed one after another. Eg. If I have 2 clients connected to the server, and both clients request from the server to draw a Circle, I want those operations to be executed in series not parallel :). I tried implementing that by Synchronizing the Threads but I didnt get what I wanted. i.e. sequential update of TCanvas, but rather a parallel one.

Comment: I know that such an implementation is "too coarse" and serializes my code, but what if I want it to be like that? what if I want to ensure that clients request will be granted one after another rather than simultaneously. Should I use the CriticalSection implementation then?

Answer (score 2):

Locking on the whole object can be much too coarse.

Imagine cases where some properties or methods are independent of others. If the lock works on a "global" level, many operations will be blocked needlessly.

From [Reduce lock granularity – Concurrency optimization](http://sourcevirtues.wordpress.com/2011/10/11/reduce-lock-granularity-concurrency/)

> So, how can we reduce lock granularity? With a short answer, by asking
>   for locks as less as possible. The basic idea is to use separate locks
>   to guard multiple independent state variables of a class, instead of
>   having only one lock in class scope.

Answer (score 1):

First things first: You don't need to implement a LOCK for each of your objects, Delphi's done that for you with the `TMonitor` class:

```
TMonitor.Enter(WhateverObject);
try
  // Your code goes here.
finally TMonitor.Leave(WhateverObject);
end;
```

just make sure you free the `WhateverObject` when your application shuts down, or else you'll run into a bug that I've opened on QC: http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=111795

Secondly, making an application multi-threading is a bit more involved. You can't just wrapp each call between `Enter`/`Leave` calls: your "locking" needs to take into account what the object does and what the access pattern is. Wrapping calls within Enter/Leave simply make sure that only one thread runs that method at any time, but race conditions are much more complex, and might arise from successive calls to your locked methods. Even those each method is locked, and only one thread ever called those methods at any given time, the state of the locked object might change between as a consequence of other thread's activity.

This kind of code would be just fine in a single-threaded application, but locking at method level is not enough when switching to multi-threaded:

```
if List.IndexOf(Something) = -1 then
  List.Add(Something);
```

Comment: @whosrdaddy +1 'TMonitor is severely broken' is what I read most of the time... maybe it has been fixed in XE3, or will be in XE4

Comment: @mjn, "severely broken" might a bit much. Looking on QC there are about 4 bug reports, relating to the exact same issue: application hangs on exit if you don't free the object that was used for `TMonitor.Enter()`.

Comment: Note that [QualityCentral has now been shut down](https://community.embarcadero.com/blogs/entry/quality-keeps-moving-forward), so you can't access `qc.embarcadero.com` links anymore. If you need access to old QC data, look at [QCScraper](http://www.uweraabe.de/Blog/2017/06/09/how-to-save-qualitycentral/).